# Маршрут в сеть за wireguard

Tags: linux, vpn, iptables, route, wireguard

Есть vpn на wireguard (далее сервер). Вот конфиг сервера:
wg0.conf

```
[Interface]
Address = 172.20.100.1/24
ListenPort = 9002
PrivateKey = uio77898hFT89UY=
SaveConfig = false

PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.100.0/24 -o ens18 -j MASQUERADE

PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 172.20.100.0/24 -o ens18 -j MASQUERADE


[Peer]

PublicKey = 4m7879878798098098
AllowedIPs = 172.20.100.50/32,172.16.100.0/24
```

Есть машинка со следующим конфигом подключенная к wireguard (далее клиент).

```
[Interface]
Address = 172.20.100.50/32
PrivateKey = CC/Ti8RUTv8gCTrwixgCsRW9QK/A89Hb6cY0D6Xy3nI=
DNS = 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT;iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.100.0/24 -o enp0s5 -j MASQUERADE

PostDown = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT;iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 172.16.100.0/24 -o enp0s5 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]

AllowedIPs = 172.20.100.0/24

PublicKey = B24s34juy0HNp6jvztoLmoTudpmKhLag7Qh+f64EUUA=

Endpoint = wireguard-ip:9002

PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Нужно все машины подключенные к wiregard пустить в сеть 172.16.100.0/24 которая находится за клиентом.

> С такой конфигурацией я захожу на клиента по его локальному адресу без проблем. А на другие адреса его локалки не получатся. ipv4.forward везде 1

Comment: вам случайно не mesh нужно поднять? хороший гайд https://insom.github.io/journal/2017/04/02/

Comment: За гайд спасибо (интересный на беглый взгляд), но пока такой задачи не ставил ))) Просто здесь реально затупил. Просто ковыряю wireguard на предмет познания

Comment: у меня схожий интерес, тем более он в скором будущем вольется в ядро.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT;iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.!!!>>>20<<<!!!.100.0/24 -o enp0s5 -j MASQUERADE

PostDown = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT;iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 172.!!!>>>20<<<!!!.100.0/24 -o enp0s5 -j MASQUERADE
```

В клиентском конфиге ошибка в адресе сети. 20 должно быть вместо 16-ти все работает.